# unable to retrieve data from Memcached cluster consistently

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have memcached cluster with two nodes. I am using pymemcache client to set and get keys from cluster.
When I am stroing key,value in cache it is storing on node1 but while retrieving sometimes it is checking same key on node2 that's why we are getting cache miss.

We got one suggestion that while storing key in cache pass node number.

Appriciate your help on below points?

1. How to avoid cache miss because we are facing continuously?
2. If we want to pass node number in set method, how to pass it?